# Legend that changes value of number in R

Tags: r, legend

Let's say I have a variable `mm = 5` which I would like to change and have the number I change it to automatically update in the legend of the graph. So where it says "no change" and "change in m" I would like it to say m = 3 and m = 5. Can this be done?

```
m <- 3  
a <-  .5 
b <-  1
c <-  .5
g <-  seq(.02,.2,by=.02)
n <-  7
r <-  .25
alpha <-  2
dt <-  1
X <-  .1
#Changed parameters
mm <- 5

A.2 = function(m = m,a,b,c,g,n,r,alpha,dt,X) { 
  1 - exp(-dt*(1/(alpha*dt)*log(1+(alpha*b*dt*m*a^2*c*X*exp(-g*n))/(a*c*X+g))))
}

all.data.g <- expand.grid(m = m,g = g,X = X)

all.data.g$a.4 <- A.2(m,a,b,c,all.data.g$g,n,r,alpha,dt,X)
all.data.g$a.5 <- A.2(mm,a,b,c,all.data.g$g,n,r,alpha,dt,X)

plot(all.data.g$g, all.data.g$a.4, xlab = 'g', ylab = 'attack rate', ylim = c(0,1), type = 'l')
lines(all.data.g$g, all.data.g$a.5, lty=2)
legend('topright', c("No change","Change in m"),lty=c(1,2))
```

Comment: Like this `legend('topright', c("No change",paste("Change in",m)),lty=c(1,2)) `? or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Right idea. I just changed "change in" to "m =" and that works. Thanks!